# Xlock: Can't grab the keyboard

Tags: screensaver, citrix

When I start Citrix Receiver in normal mode, screensaver of host machine get activated as per expectation. But when I connect the same session in Fullscreen mode then screensaver of host machine flickers for fraction of second.

I am using `xlock` as a screensaver utility. Afrer debugging, `xlock` abryputly exits with an error "Can not grab the kayboard"

But, if I took rdesktop of same machine in fullscreen mode then, I do not face such issue.

What can be the cause of this issue ?